# Why no error for unused partial specialisation?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

The specialisation of `Foo` below will never be used; Clang gives a warning, and GCC doesn't.

```
template <typename>
struct Foo                { static const int value = 0; };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ...Ts>
struct Foo<C<Ts..., int>> { static const int value = 1; };
```

Why does this not result in an error?

The following code demonstrates this:

```
template <typename...>
struct Bar {};

static_assert(!Foo<Bar<char,double,int>>::value,"");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further on why this can never be used (it's not obvious to me just looking at it)?

Comment: @MarkB Partial specialization matching depends on template argument deduction, and the pack here won't be deduced (a pack expansion that's not the last template argument in a template argument list is a non-deduced context).

Comment: I've added an example above which compiles without error on both GCC and Clang. (The warning from Clang is also quite absolute about this.)

Comment: I'm guessing it's because determining whether a partial specialization can be used or not is infeasible in general. But I can't prove it.

Comment: @kerrekSB no, that is the question.  I think the OP knows that the specialization is "unreachable", the OP is asking **why** it isn't an error to have an unreachable specialization.

Comment: Clause 14 labels a number of constructs ill-formed but with no diagnostic required, pretty much because diagnosing them would be infeasible; surprisingly enough, a partial specialization that will never be used isn't one of them...

Comment: OK, fair enough. No answer then.

Comment: @T.C. But it isn't ill-formed either.  Nor is there a diagnostic required.  I can think of a reason why we wouldn't want this kind of thing to be ill-formed: what if it is sometimes hard to detect if a template specialization would be unreachable?  What kinds of unreachability should be ill-formed?  Maybe creating a maybe-unreachable template partial specialization could be sometimes useful, as it is easier to splurt out the unreachable template specialization than determine if it is reachable?  Maybe not...

Comment: OP, am I correct in that your question is "why is an 'unreachable' template specialization not an error?"

Comment: @Yakk You are basically outlining the case for "ill-formed; no diagnostic required" - i.e., implementations are allowed but not required to diagnose them :)

Comment: @T.C. The result of compiling ill-formed programs is undefined.  The result of a specialization you cannot instantiate can be well defined.  As an example of the difference, the result of a function template with no valid specialization is defined to be an ill-formed program with no diagnostic required: which means as a programmer, I cannot use a function template with no valid specialization in a few cases where they are useful, and if I accidentally do so my program is not well-formed.  I can, however, use unreachable specializations and know that my program is well-formed.

Comment: A case where a function template with no valid specialization is useful is the "eliminate this method from a class template where the type argument is `int`".  I can do `template<class Unused=void> typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same<int, T>::value >::type not_an_int() const { std::cout << "not an int\n"; }` except for that rule blocks me.

Comment: @T.C. full snippet: `template<class T> struct foo { template<class Unused=void> typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same<int, T>::value >::type not_an_int() const { std::cout << "not an int\n"; } };`  This is illegal under C++ due to there being no valid specialization of `foo<int>::not_an_int<?>()` by my reading of the standard.  Now I see a reason **why** they did that (to allow more, smarter `template` function checks in the future that catch more invalid code prior to instantiation), but it does get in the way as well.

Comment: @Yakk But you can always do `template<class T1 = T>` and test `is_same<int, T1>`.

Comment: @T.C. `foo<int> f; f.not_an_int<void>();` prints `"not an int"` but it lies.

Comment: @Yakk Well, yes, though that can be said for a number of "using `enable_if_t` as default template argument" cases of SFINAE...

Comment: @user2023370 specialization below is used in case `Foo<Bar<char,double,int>` **`, int`** `>::value`, but this time program won't compile, because it calls `Foo<Bar<...>, int>`, when `Foo` can deal with only 1 template parameter.

Comment: And that you can't use it, because `Foo` isn't adapted to usage like that, seems to be your, not compiler's, error.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus No, watch where that `,int` in the specialization is.

Answer (score 2):

Defining something and not using it isn't error. If it were, in each program you `#include<vector>` you would have to use [`vector<bool>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/).

Comment: Funny. Maybe I should also declare `vec tor <b$$l>:`

Comment: There's a difference between something that's just unused and something that can't possibly be used.